# Is there a way to change one of parameters in OCMock and continue running the stubbed function

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, ocmock

Hello I'm trying to change the parameter of a function I have stubbed.
I see in logs that my stub is called successfully, and I want to change one of the paramters and run the original function. Can I do that with OCMock?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
.... 

id testMgrMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:testClassInstance];

OCMStub([testMgrMock addRequestWithMethod:OCMOCK_ANY
                                     path:OCMOCK_ANY
                               parameters:OCMOCK_ANY
                                  headers:OCMOCK_ANY
                                     body:OCMOCK_ANY
                                 delegate:OCMOCK_ANY
                             successBlock:OCMOCK_ANY
                             failureBlock:OCMOCK_ANY]).
andDo(^(NSInvocation* invocation){
    NSString* path = @"http://addressnotexi.st";
    [invocation setArgument:&path atIndex:2];

    // here I want to call "addRequestWithMethod:path:parameters:header (etc)" 
    // on a real object with the parameter "path" changed to my string

    [invocation invoke];
});
......
```

the line `[invocation invoke];` gives me bad_exec crash. Even if I don't change the parameter.

How to do it properly? Is it possible at all?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried telling the invocation to retain its arguments before calling invoke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

Need to reaarange code in the following way:

before `@implementation`:

```
NSString invalidPath = @"http://theaddressthatdoesnotexis.ts";
```

And the code will look like this:

```
.... 

id testMgrMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:testClassInstance];

OCMStub([testMgrMock addRequestWithMethod:OCMOCK_ANY
                                     path:[OCMArg isNotEqual:invalidPath]
                               parameters:OCMOCK_ANY
                                  headers:OCMOCK_ANY
                                     body:OCMOCK_ANY
                                 delegate:OCMOCK_ANY
                             successBlock:OCMOCK_ANY
                             failureBlock:OCMOCK_ANY]).
andDo(^(NSInvocation* invocation){
    [invocation setArgument:&invalidPath atIndex:3];
    [invocation invoke];
});
......
```

In shorter words. My invoke was working but if was calling itself

Comment: Of course! I totally missed that, too. You basically created an infinite recursion. Glad that you found it.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I ran into this same problem and the example code above still has the issue.  If you call

Comment: Just wanted to add that I ran into the same issue and the code above will still have the infinite recursion because you are calling [invocation invoke].  Instead, I believe what you want to do is replace the arguments, then call andForwardToRealObject, which will bypass the partial mock and call the real function but with your mocked params.